# Adding xmlns namespace in an Xdocument

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-xml

I want to create an XDocument with whcih will look like below:

```xml
<configurations xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://msn.com/csl/featureConfigurationv2">
  <configuration>
    …
  </configuration>
</configurations>
```

I am facing problem in adding the second attribute. I am trying this:

```cs
XYZ.Element("configurations").SetAttributeValue("xmlns", "http://msn.com/csl/featureConfigurationv2");
```

But its not adding the attribute.

Can you suggest something else please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```cs
XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://msn.com/csl/featureConfigurationv2"); 
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    // Do XDeclaration Stuff
    new XElement("configurations",
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns, ns),
        // Do XElement Stuff
     )
);
```

and this way too

```cs
XNamespace ns = "http://msn.com/csl/featureConfigurationv2";
XElement configurations = new XElement(ns + "configurations",
    new XAttribute("xmlns", "http://msn.com/csl/featureConfigurationv2"),
    // Do XElement Stuff
);
```

Comment: Why this answer has been accepted? Both snippets are totally invalid. The first one causes compile-time error, and the second one crashes in runtime.